# Place form on top and disable others behind it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Main Form and a Other Form.
The Main Form is always open, and at some time it will launch Other Form.

I tried:

```
form.TopMost = true;
```

But this only places the form on top. The Form behind (Main Form) still can be accessible.

How can I get the same behavior like when I do OpenFileDialog, and disable the main form behind it?

(Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [make your form modal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). To do this, use [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) instead of `Show` to display it (the same way you do with a dialog).

Also, note that forms shown with `ShowDialog` are not actually closed and disposed when you click their Close button, so you should dispose them manually. The usual way to handle their lifetime is to use a `using` construct:

```
using (var form = new SomeForm())
{
    form.ShowDialog();
    // do stuff after the dialog is closed
}
```

Comment: I totally forget that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

form.showdialog(); where form is the the top form to be launched.so while lauching the top form just add form.showdialog()